# Indian citizen. Moving to Brunei. Working as freelancer for US company. In which account do I get my salary transferred?

Tags: taxes, income-tax, india, income, salary

I am an Indian citizen living in the US for last 4 years. My husband will be transferred to Brunei starting July and I will join him too.

My US employer wants me to continue working as a freelancer with them. I have below questions:

1) Where can I get my salary transferred? Indian account or Brunei account? Should Indian account be NRE?

2) How do I report income and pay taxes in India? (Brunei has no taxes.)

Please please guide. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

From the facts you are deemed Non-Resident Indian for tax purposes.

> Where can I get my salary transferred? Indian account or Brunei account? Should Indian account be NRE?

Where ever its convenient to you. If its in India it should be in NRE/NRO type accounts. As an NRI one should not have regular savings account in India.

> How do I report income and pay taxes in India?

As an NRI you are not liable to pay taxes in India for income earned outside India. There is no need to report the income either in India.